# looping inside a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I am nesting a list inside a dictionary. I have tried to loop it, but the output is showing each letter instead of the entire word and it is not showing the other value in the list .

```
favorite_languages = {
   'jen': ['python', 'ruby'],
   'sarah': ['c'],
   'edward': ['ruby', 'go'],
   'phil': ['python', 'haskell'],
   }

for name,languages in favourite_languages.items():
print("\n" + name.title() + "'s fav lang are:")
    for language in languages:
        print("\t" + language.title())
```

So, the outputs is -

```
Jen's fav lang are:
    P
    Y
    T
    H
    O
    N
```

Comment: Works fine for me if you only use one spelling of `favourite`, and fix the indentation.

Comment: I get a total different ouput, and mine is correct, try to fix the indentation

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out the error. It worked for me now.

Comment: I had another dictionary spelled 'favourite'  open at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing identation and small typos your code works for me:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BDoIwDAbg@56i6UWIhIs3Ep9EjalS2HQOsg0NMT47shHQGHfr@vdr297LxmyGoaJ701nl@ajJ1B3V7GALTwHjwwsbLGCHbUxjBmi7U4@HbGo7siRj4Lz8cfkgW8bPmB1n6mbptlLpH1GSu7LWIfISomosGLpxBp9zlIE/V@ZjdXNJWkS5tcr4BPcGYR2B3CuvOUnHElcuAFEEslxgGmfCrpkLSxZ6Ir9ZH9i5P9OpGIY3)

```
favourite_languages = {
    "jen": ["python", "ruby"],
    "sarah": ["c"],
    "edward": ["ruby", "go"],
    "phil": ["python", "haskell"],
}

for name, languages in favourite_languages.items():
    print("\n" + name.title() + "'s fav lang are:")
    for language in languages:
        print("\t" + language.title())
```

Output:

```
Jen's fav lang are:
    Python
    Ruby

Sarah's fav lang are:
    C

Edward's fav lang are:
    Ruby
    Go

Phil's fav lang are:
    Python
    Haskell
```

Comment: @Abhishmita Don't forget to accept answer if it is correct. It is nice if all StackOverflow questions have accepted answers, even if solution was obvious. To accept answer go to beginning of my answer and to the left from there is Check Mark to accept it. Also there is Upper/Down arrows to UpVote and DownVote.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had no idea about it. I tried to upvote it, but it does not allow me to.

Comment: @Abhishmita You'll be able to UpVote any answer probably starting from reputation of 15 score, so very soon. Also you can upvote (in the future) not only answers to you questions, but any answers of other people's questions. Accepting any answer to YOUR question you are able even with reputation of 1.

Comment: Thanks @Arty, you're the best